# How do we formulate multiple conditions in a single column in Tableau? Case When or IF Else?

Tags: case, tableau-api

I have one question.. My file contains 3 column.
Column A- Name,
Column B - Transaction count.
Column C - Code

However, I only need to count the 2 codes out of these multiple codes.

I Tried using this formula but i am having incorrect results:

Count(if(ISNULL([name])

AND [Code]<> 'ABA'

AND [Code]<> 'ABC'

Then [Transaction Count]

END)

How do we formulate multiple conditions in a single column?

Comment: Can you share your workbook so we can look at the data in those columns please?

Comment: SUM instead of COUNT? Your formula looks ok, the aggregation may be incorrect - depends on your data.

Comment: I'm assuming [Code] can be either 'ABA' or 'ABC' but not both at the same time. I'd try checking for that like `... AND ([Code]<> 'ABA' OR [Code]<> 'ABC')...`

Comment: Make sure you understand what Count() does